# Restoring .proto file from descriptor string. Possible?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Is it possible to decompile a string containing Protocol Buffers descriptor back to .proto file?

Say I have a long string like

`\n\file.proto\u001a\u000ccommon.proto\"\u00a3\u0001\n\nMsg1Request\u0012\u0017\n\u0006common\u0018\u0001 ...` etc.

I need to restore .proto, not necessary exactly as it was but compilable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it should be possible to get some thing close get original definition. I do not know of any existing code to do it (hopefully some one else will).

Hava a look at how protocol buffers itself handles the String.

Basically

1. convert the string to bytes (using charset="ISO-8859-1" in java), it will then be a **Protocol-Buffer message**(format=**FileDescriptorProto** in java). The **FileDescriptorProto** is built as part of the Protocol-Buffers install.
2. Extract the data in the **Protocol-Buffer message**

Here is a File-Descriptor protocol displayed in the [Protocol-Buffer editor](http://code.google.com/p/protobufeditor/)

[image]

Comment: I'll definitely try it. If I find a tool I'll report. If not, I/m going to do it myself but not soon...

Answer (score 6):

In C++, the `FileDescriptor` interface has a method `DebugString()` which formats the descriptor contents in `.proto` syntax -- i.e. exactly what you want.  In order to use it, you first need to write code to convert the raw `FileDescriptorProto` to a `FileDescriptor`, using the `DescriptorPool` interface.

Something like this should do it:

```
#include <google/protobuf/descriptor.h>
#include <google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto fileProto;
  fileProto.ParseFromFileDescriptor(0);
  google::protobuf::DescriptorPool pool;
  const google::protobuf::FileDescriptor* desc =
      pool.BuildFile(fileProto);
  std::cout << desc->DebugString() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

You need to feed this program the raw bytes of the FileDescriptorProto, which you can get by using Java to encode your string to bytes using the ISO-8859-1 charset.

Also note that the above doesn't work if the file imports any other files -- you would have to load those imports into the `DescriptorPool` first.

Comment: It prints only first message. Am I doing something wrong or it needs to be modified to print multiple messages?

Comment: Everything that's in the FileDescriptorProto should get printed.

Comment: this is a hack. It seems that DebugString() can only print out the descriptor with proto2 syntax. So it will be some trouble if you have to use proto3 syntax. :(

Comment: To be fair, proto3 didn't exist when I posted this.

Comment: The descriptor file can also be gotten using `protoc --include_source_info --include_imports
 --descriptor_set_out=foo.desc foo.proto`