# C# Protobuf: How to deserialize a TextFormat-based string of an unknown type?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I'm new to Protobuf, hopefully this is not too stupid a question. I have a string in what I believe is ProtoBuf's TextFormat, something like:

```
model.messages.Request { RequestNum: 123 Sender: "Test" Content { value: 45678 valuescale: 1 } }
```

The real string is a lot more extensive mind you with many more properties etc.
My goal would be to deserialize this string in C#, e.g. something like (pseudo-code)

```
var obj = DeserializeThisSomehow("model.messages.Request { RequestNum: 123 Sender: \"Test\" Content { value: 45678 valuescale: 1 } }");

var numProperty = ((dynamic)obj).RequestNum;
// or maybe something like ...
var numProperty = obj.Properties["RequestNum"];
```

Is this possible somehow? My issues are that

1. The input string seems to be in TextFormat, and I have not found anything in Protobuf's C# API yet that would let you deserialize anything from that format
2. I don't have any type information about the resulting object, so I don't know in advance what properties it will have / could not write any specific format specification for it (*)

Is there any way to do this?

(*) as for issue no. 2 - I do, however, have some decompiled java code which I believe is the java code that was generated by running protoc on the original .proto file. Among other things, this includes a string of the descriptor data, something like

```
"\n\031RequestMessage.proto\022\024...........
```

Maybe this can be used to reverse-engineer the format/.proto spec? But not sure how, I've only found this approach: [Restoring .proto file from descriptor string. Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418655/restoring-proto-file-from-descriptor-string-possible)  but don't seem to be able to apply this (e.g. protobuf's C# api doesn't seem to have any FileDescriptorProto type)

Thanks

Comment: Which protobuf library are you using, exactly?

Comment: I'm using Google.Protobuf v3.5.0 from nuget

Comment: Right - we don't support the old TextFormat at all. (The hope with proto3 having a well-specified JSON format was that that would be used instead.)

Comment: Oh, right .. thanks Jon. Just off the top of your head, do you recall if any of the older versions (on NuGet) still have some support/features for this?

Comment: Yes, if you use `Google.ProtocolBuffers` (from https://github.com/jskeet/protobuf-csharp-port) that supports `TextFormat` - but it won't support proto3 messages.

Comment: It sounds like you should try to track down the original .proto file and a binary representation of the message though.

Comment: Thanks Jon, very much appreciate your input. Will try with Google.ProtocolBuffers.
Unfortunately, I only have access to strings of these formats (purely a consumer of some output of a corporate IT systems) & have no way to e.g. get binary data or the underlying proto files, so have to try and make do with this somehow - your input goes a long way for that though, should be able to work something out hopefully

Comment: For the second part, `DynamicMessage` (also only available in the proto2 C# port) may be your friend - if you convert your string into binary, then load that as a `FileDescriptor`... it's a bit hairy though.

Comment: I ended up managing to get all FileDescriptorProtos from the Java code I had & saved their binary data to disk - then loaded these into  ProtoGen, which I modified to load these ones directly instead of .proto files, and generated the C# message code based on that. Thanks again for your input on this, helped a lot!