# gRPC: Generating Proto definitions from compiled protos

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

Just wondering if it is possible to go in the "reverse" direction of GRPC compilation. I have a previously compiled .g.cs gRPC service file but I do not have the .proto file that was used to build it.

Is there a tool / way to generate the original .proto file from the compiled .g.cs file?

Thanks!

Comment: If you've got the generated protobuf messages, that will have a file descriptor which is the sort of "compiled" version of the .proto file... but it's still not the human-readable form. I don't know of any tool to reverse engineer it, but you could probably do it by hand for a small service.

Comment: Sorry when you say the generated protobuf messages. Do you mean the actual .g.cs file that it outputs when compiled using the compiled C# flag. Those two files are all I have :( I guess doing it by hand might be my only option....

Comment: There are two sets of files - one set with the services generated by the gRPC protoc plugin, and one set with the messages generated by the core protoc plugin.

Comment: Yes, I believe I have them both. So you think the best solution would be to manually rebuild the original .proto file from the compiled files?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd probably do. There *may* be tools to go back from a binary descriptor to a .proto file, but I don't know of them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418655 has a couple of options, but that was from a long time ago, and it doesn't look convenient...

Comment: Alright thanks a bunch, Daisy. You're the best!

Answer (score 0):

See Daisy's comments above. There seems to be no easy or automated way to do this as of April 2018. Manually re-creating the original .proto file seems to be the way to go.